# Kaddish for children

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus, kaddish, hacham-ovadia-yosef

I heard some rabbanim say that if a baby or child is over the age of 30 days, one should say kaddish for him for a year (11 months) while I have heard others say that 11 months is only for a parent and for the rest it is a month.

What are the different minhagim and please do add the opinion of Hacham Ovadia Yosef?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/97941/15256